# Можете помочь с задачей Java?

Tags: java

Какой из указанных конструкторов может быть добавлен в описание класса А?

```
class A {
    char ch;
    int digit;
}
```

Выберите один ответ:

a. A (char ch, int digit) { this.ch = ch; this.digit = digit; }

b. A (char ch, short digit) { ch = digit; digit = ch; }

c. A(int charCode) { ch = charCode; digit = charCode; }

d. A (int charCode) { ch = digit = charCode; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. так как остальные будут выбрасывать исключения из-за типов. SOF - это не то место для подобных вопросов, к слову